# Xcode package manager lost the packages when I pull the changes from the repo

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

It's not happening all the time but at least happens once a day.
I and my colleague are working on the same project & we use the swift package manager for managing the libraries... but almost every time when we pull the changes, both will see this Xcode error:

"Missing package product X"

and have to reset the package cache to be able to build the project.

The Xcode error is attached!

Does anyone know what's the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? Seems to switch from cocoapods was a big mistake